# Sampling Random Index from ndarray According to Array Elements

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an ndarray where the elements sum to 1. My problem is quite simple, I want to randomly sample indices of this array where the probability of getting each index is the value of the corresponding element. Now, I want to do this many times and in large arrays with many dimensions so I was hoping to use `np.random.choice` or something similar rather than a for-loop but I can't seem to figure it out.

For example, if I have the ndarray

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.0, 0.2], [0.6, 0.2]])
```

I want to never get index `(0,0)` get `(0,1)` and `(1,1)` at a rate of 20 % each and get `(1,0)` at a rate of 60 %.

Is there a good and fast way of doing this that you know of? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `flatten` the array (from 2D to 1D) and use `np.random.choice`. Then you need to project the 1D index back to 2D using `np.unravel_index`:

```
np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(a.size, p = a.flatten()), a.shape)
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! I was going to comment and say that this is too slow for my purposes but `np.random.choice` has a `size` parameter and the time scales really well in this parameter. (For future reference)

Comment: This solution also works for arrays of an arbitrary dimension btw.